# premake not supporting vs2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build, tinyxml, premake, tinyxml++

Here is my senario:

- I am trying to build TinyXML++ using vs2012
- Supposedly, premake is required to generate a *.sln for vs studio to build TinyXML++ lib files.
- But premake4.4 beta, I supposed the latest, seems not to support vs2012; It cannot build a *.sln for vs2012
- I can generate *sln for vs2010, but it won't pass a vs2012 build because the #`include "stdafx.h"` in **ticpp.cpp**, one of the cpp files in TinyXML++ project, gets error of **cannot open source file**

So I am wondering, how can I get around this problem? Thanks. Anyone has done this before? Thanks.

Comment: According to the premake website, there is no support for VS2012. You could try a) building with MinGW b) creating a project in VS by hand using the same parameters found in the premake scripts c) using VS2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on Windows, you can grab [the latest nightly build](https://sourceforge.net/projects/premake/files/Premake/nightlies/). Otherwise, grab and build [the latest sources](https://bitbucket.org/premake/premake-stable/), which do support Visual Studio 2012.

A release candidate build is coming soon, but there are still a few more bugs to get fixed.